# New Formula for the Payback Period (PBP) of an investment

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-functions, article-writing

**$\bf1$. Context:**
Payback Period (or **PBP**): Time required to recover initial investment in a project.
[image: Table]
Payback Period = $\bf3.25$ **years** (to recover the $50,000$)

**$\bf2$. Unliked Formula:** PBP = $\frac{\text{Cost of Investment}}{\text{Average Annual Cashflow}}$

**Reason:** Formula assumes uniform cashflows for all the years unlike our example.

**$\bf 3$. Question/Problem:**
How to write the formula for PBP so that it looks neat and works for non-unifrom cashflows?

**$\bf 4$. My take**:
I came up with PBP = $n |\left(\sum(\text{CashInflow})-\sum(\text{CashOutflow})=0\right)$. But this makes use of "such that" and also doesn't capture the $0.25$ year thing.

Comment: @ryang The given formula assumes uniform cashflows which may not be the case.

Comment: @ryang I have shortened the question. Please give it a read.

Comment: @ryang I dislike the formula for failing to output $3.25$.